# Clonezilla hangs

Tags: clonezilla

When I run Clonezilla Live from CD on my laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 (no other OS) everything works fine until the very end when the laptop freezes and I have to reboot it. The .img file is saved and appears to be OK as it has a size of 100Gb. How can I test it without installing it?

And, does anyone else have this problem with Clonezilla hanging?

Comment: 1. Clonezilla performs well for me, I use the stable iso files to create CD boot disks or nowadays USB pendrives; 2 The only way to **really** test an image is to get another drive of at least the same size as the original one and restore from the image. Do **not** boot the computer with both the original drive and the cloned copy connected. Boot with only the cloned copy connected in order to succeed.

Comment: I prefer using Disks instead of Clonezilla to make system images. It's more basic but reliable. If you have a lot of unused space, eg in your root partition, I'd suggest shrinking it first before imaging.